# Where is the nuget packages folder located on a hosted build server using TFS?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I need to execute a command line utility from a package that is downloaded as part of nuget package restore in the TFS build process.

On my local computer that is stored in c:\users\me.nuget*

I've tried every permutation of that on TFS without success.  I've also tried \mydir\packages with no success as well.

The biggest problem is that I have to run the package restore step before being able to see any sort of feedback from the log. That's some slow debugging.

Any ideas?  Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nuget package cache folder is in C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages, but it will be cleaned after build if you are using Hosted build server.
The simple way to verify:

1. Add NuGet restore or .Net Core Restore build step to restore packages
2. Add PowerShell build step to list files in C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages

Code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages
```

3. Queue build and check the PowerShell step log (the packages’ will be listed in the log)
4. Remove/disable NuGet restore or .Net Core Restore build step > Save build definition
5. Queue build
6. The build will be failed, because the path does not exist.

So, the packages need to be restored before build solution/project if aren’t existing. You can add packages to source control and map to build agent to deal with the issue of too long time takes to restore packages.

Comment: That was is it! Thanks a bunch. Side question, is that path consistent? e.g. A variable for that path. $(Foo). Could not find one for that location.

Comment: @trevorc There isn't the build-in variable for that path.

Answer (score 7):

With the latest nuget/msbuild the packages folder is held under the active user's profile directory, so an appropriate Powershell command is

```
Get-ChildItem $(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages
```

This currently evaluates on the VSTS 2017 Hosted build agent to C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages but by using the variable you are insulated from any changes made.

Comment: I was able to use this with my on-prem ADS. After I switched my project over to `PackageReference`, the packages were no longer being pushed to the remote repo. I had to use the local package cache on the server instead. In my case, the PS command ended up being `gci -Path $Env:UserProfile\.nuget\packages\squirrel* -Filter Squirrel.exe -Recurse`. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that in the devops nuget caching doc they use `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to @Paul Hatcher's answer:

I also faced the same problem in Azure DevOps build pipeline where a specific package and nuget packages directory could not be found.
It is a `Xamarin.Forms` app based on a `.net standard` library where no `packages` folder exists. I later noticed in build logs that the packages are restored to nuget folder under user's profile. However this particular case is not documented on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts#agent-variables.

[image]

That means @Paul Hatcher's answer is also valid if you try to reference nuget package folder directly from your build pipeline. This ($(UserProfile).nuget\packages) should actually be a (standard) predefined build variable.

Comment: This is what solved it for me. We recently migrated from packages.config and for some reason the `/packages/` folder moved from `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\src\packages` to the user profile location.