# Nuget package does not copy content (XML Files)

Tags: tfs, nuget-package, nuget-server

We are using TFS build steps for creating nuget packages. So automatically TFS does this job, i mean, it creates firstly nuspec file and then creates nupkg.

So, this package contains my xml settings but the problem it does not copy into the debug/relase folder when I add this nuget package to a project. But I see that the content is added into the project, the problem is only these content files not copies to the build folder.

I saw that there is some solution for creating nuget package manually. (I also tried these but not worked for me even though) TFS creates all things by itself.

Well, my content's properties are like that

[image]

So i couold not solve this problem. I use NuGet 3.3.

Comment: What's the build are you using? vNext or XAML? If you are using vNext build, could you find the nuget packages folder located on the hosted build server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559902/where-is-the-nuget-packages-folder-located-on-a-hosted-build-server-using-tfs/41564070#41564070

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015#create-and-update-the-nuspec-file

Answer (score 1):

The contentFiles section of the nuspec for packages.config projects, it only add the files into the project. If you want to change the files' CopytoOutPut property, you need to use an install.ps1 script. You could refer to the [this discussion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1908).

Following thread provide some code snippet of the install.ps1.

[Set content files to "copy local : always" in a nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package)

So you need to add the install.ps1 script into tools folder for your packages when TFS creating this package.

Answer (score 0):

> it does not copy into the debug/relase folder when I add this nuget package to a project

I saw this solution, or variations of it, in similar questions. It worked for me using .Net 8.

Add the below code to your `csproj` file for the project that is consuming your nuget package (that has xml docs in it)

```
<Target Name="_ResolveCopyLocalNuGetPackageXmls" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" Condition="Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Note that it will copy all corresponding xml files, if they exist. If you don't want this, you may have to play around with the condition.

Note also that you may have to add it to some test project files as well. In my case I was consuming doc header for swagger and all my integration tests failed because the xml file I needed wasn't in the test project's bin folder